# Ansible how to reference the variables from different tasks files

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to be able to reference the variable vpc_info registered by file create-public-vpc from file create-public-sunbet

/etc/ansible/roles/ec2/tasks/main.yml

```
# tasks file for ec2-provision

- name:
  import_tasks: create-vpc.yml
  import_tasks: create-public-subnet.yml
```

/etc/ansible/roles/ec2/vars/main.yml

```
---
# vars file for ec2-provision

################################### designate python interpreter  ########################

ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8


############################## VPC INFO #########################################
vpc_name: "My VPC"
vpc_cidr_block: "10.0.0.0/16"
aws_region: "us-east-1"


################################### VPC Subnet ###############################################
aws_zone: "us-east-1a"
# Subnets
vpc_public_subnet_cidr: "10.0.0.0/24"

# Subnet
vpc_private_subnet_cidr: "10.0.1.0/24"
```

create-vpc.yml

```
- name: Create AWS VPC
  ec2_vpc_net:  
    name: "{{ vpc_name }}"
    cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    state: present
  register: vpc_info    

- name: Set vpc_info as fact
  set_fact: 
    vpc_info_fact: "{{ vpc_info }}"
```

create-public-sunbet.yml

```
- name:  print vpc_info_fact
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['vpc_info_fact'] }}"


- name: Create Public Subnet in VPC 
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_info['vpc']['id'] }}"
    cidr: "{{ vpc_public_subnet_cidr }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    az: "{{ aws_zone }}" 
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: Public Subnet
  register: public_subnet_info
```

When I run `ansible-playbook` ec2-provision.yml, the error message is as follows:

```
[root@VM-0-14-centos tasks]# ansible-playbook ec2-provision.yml 
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /etc/ansible/roles/EC2/tasks/main.yml, line 4, column 3, found a duplicate dict key (import_tasks). Using last defined value
only.

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [EC2 : print vpc_info_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'vpc_info_fact' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/EC2/tasks/create-public-subnet.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:  print vpc_info_fact\n  ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: The problem is not being in different files but in different plays. If those tasks are called in different plays, use `set_fact` to store the var in first play. Then call it "normally" in the next one (use `hostvars` if it was registered on a different host).

Comment: Please edit your question with an [MCVE](/help/mcve). We have no idea how you set fact exactly, on which host, in which play and how/where you are trying to reuse that var later.

Comment: I tried to `set_ fact` a variable and then access it from int the **create-public-sunbet.yml** file (use `hostvars ['localhost']`), but the return value has no variables `vpc_info_fac`t and `vpc_info`

Comment: I've already read this comment 3 times. Deleting it and re-pasting it and/or duplicating it on your question and below answer will not tell us how you set fact exactly, using which host from which inventory, in which play, loading your files with which module (include, include_tasks, role...), in which playbook. Etc. Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and create a **real** [MCVE](/help/mcve) that you add as an **edit to you question**, not in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I edited the problem description again

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in the must read help article [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: That being said.... have a look at the very first warning in the output. There is absolutely no problem with registering the variable and using it. You can drop the set_fact which is no use here. As is your first file is simly not executed because you main task file is not valid and only taking into account the second include. Put them in separate list elements.

Comment: Since I'm not entirely sure my last comment was clear: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/1b8c2e647b6aea1de9781130f20eba08

Comment: I see what you mean, create-vpc.yml is not running , I modified the main file and it can run successfully. I'll take your advice, but I'm off work now and correct my question tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the **variable** value as a **fact** once the variable is created and then you'd access the corresponding **fact** via **hostvars**.

For example:

```
- name: Create AWS VPC
  ec2_vpc_net:  
     name: "{{ vpc_name }}"
     cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
     region: "{{ aws_region }}"
     aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
     state: present
  register: vpc_info  

- name: Set vpc_info as fact
  set_fact: vpc_info_fact="{{ vpc_info }}"
```

To access it from a different file, we have the following task:

```
- name: Create Public Subnet in VPC 
  ec2_vpc_subnet:
     vpc_id: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['vpc_info']['vpc']['id'] }}"
     cidr: "{{ vpc_public_subnet_cidr }}"
     region: "{{ aws_region }}"
     az: "{{ aws_zone }}" 
     aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
     state: present
     tags:
        Name: Public Subnet
  register: public_subnet_info
```

Comment: I tried to `set_ fact` a variable and then access it from int the  **create-public-sunbet.yml** file (use `hostvars ['localhost']`), but the return value has no variables `vpc_info_fact`  and `vpc_info`

Comment: If you use those 2 different task files in the same play, there is no need to set_fact. You can directly use the registered var.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I know how to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.yml` contains a tasks with two modules. It should be

```
- name: Create VPC
  import_tasks: create-vpc.yml

- name: Create Public Subnets
  import_tasks: create-public-subnet.yml
```

The running playbooks prints the warning about that issue.

```
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /etc/ansible/roles/EC2/tasks/main.yml, line 4, column 3, found a duplicate dict key (import_tasks). Using last defined value
only.
```

Ansible cannot have more then one module per task - and `include_tasks` is a module. It picks the last module, if there are multiple modules in one task (after writing the warning message and not exiting).

This is the main problem of all your issues. Everything else looks ok to me.